# Why can't i redirect an action to another action in Struts2?

Tags: java, struts2

i am using Struts2. I have a dialog box with a list of persons that is update through the "search_users" action. Next to this list i have a form that you can use to add another person by calling the "add_user" action when the form is submitted.

What i'm trying to do is that, once the add_user action is performed, the list gets updated using the "search_user" action.

I tried using the result type "redirect" in the struts.xml like this:

```
<action name="search_users" class="org.apache.struts.gestion_edt.controller.adm_proyectos.BLSubequipo" method="searchUsers">
            <result name="success">list.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action name="add_user" class="org.apache.struts.gestion_edt.controller.adm_proyectos.BLTipoEntregable" method="addUser">
            <result name="success" type="redirectAction">search_users</result>
        </action>
```

But that doesn't work. What am i doing wrong? Is there something i should add to the struts.xml file that i'm not aware of?

This is the error mesage i get:

```
"Caused by: There is no result type defined for type 'redirect-action' mapped with name 'success'.  Did you mean 'redirectAction'? - result - file:/.../struts.xml:59:44
    at ..."
```

Comment: Starting Struts2.1x or something similar redirect-action was changed to camel casing like redirectAction, what is the issue you got using redirectAction ?, also which version of S2 you are using ?

Comment: The version is 2.3.1.2. The issue is the project just wont build because of the defective struts.xml file. The error message shows a little more detail.

Comment: for 2.3.1.2 redirectAction is the correct one

Comment: check if my answer resolves your issue

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Current Configuration:

```
<action name="add_user" class="org.apache.struts.gestion_edt.controller.adm_proyectos.BLTipoEntregable" method="addUser">
   <result name="success" type="redirectAction">search_users</result>
</action>
```

As per the [documentation](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1.2/docs/redirect-action-result.html) correct format is:

```
<action name="add_user" class="org.apache.struts.gestion_edt.controller.adm_proyectos.BLTipoEntregable" method="addUser">
    <result type="redirectAction">
        <param name="actionName">search_users</param>
        <!--<param name="namespace">/secure</param> This is optional if your action where you are redirecting is in the same namespace you can leave this, if your action is in some other name space then provide the namespace--> 
    </result>
</action>
```

Comment: Thank you! That solved my problem. I tried it that way but then i did include the package parameter even though they both belong to the same package. I appreciate the help.

Comment: How do you tell them you go to redirect on SUCCESS ?

Comment: @mprabhat u have written class-name `BLTipoEntregable` at both the places . shouldn't it be `BLSubequipo` at the first definition ??? as per the question

Answer (score 2):

Currently using **Struts 2.3.20**, this works:

```
<result type="redirectAction">myAction</result>
```

I have not confirmed in prior versions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a big Struts guy but based on the documentation it looks like your redirect is not syntactically correct: http://struts.apache.org/2.1.6/docs/redirect-action-result.html

```
<package name="public" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="login" class="...">
        <!-- Redirect to another namespace -->
        <result type="redirect-action">
            <param name="actionName">dashboard</param>
            <param name="namespace">/secure</param>
        </result>
    </action>
</package>
```

Comment: Thank you, i just tried that but it didn't work either. I will edit the post and add the error message.

Comment: redirect-action was for older versions of Struts2, newer versions use redirectAction (change in convention of separating words). Otherwise, your example should work fine.